# How to make background transparent in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-5

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush bg-transparent">
            <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">A fourth item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">And a fifth one</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

How do I make the background color transparent so it would take the color of the bigger div?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **bg-transparent** class for every *li* children as well:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: cyan;">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush bg-transparent">
    <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">An item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">A second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">A fourth item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">And a fifth one</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the above example, only the third item is not transparent.